# Thymleaf switch statement in table

Tags: switch-statement, thymeleaf

I want to set my `tr` class to `bg-success` when the status is equals 'EXECUTED'. Here is my code:

```
<th:block th:switch="${order.status}">
    <tr th:case="'EXECUTED'" class="bg-success">
    <tr th:case="*" class="bg-warning">
    <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
```

It's obvious that I append two `tr` rows and don't close the first one, but in reality it's just one appended.

One solution is to rewrite the `<td>...</td>` in every case but it's a poor one. Is there any better solution without rewriting the `<td>..</td>` or using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps :

```
<tr th:class="${order.status.equals('EXECUTED') ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-warning'}">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```